# Poisson distribution and exponential decay

Tags: poisson-distribution

The definition of Poisson distribution says that in this series the arrival of one sample is independent of the time the previous sample came. 
As well as it is said that Poisson distribution has exponential decay, which means dependence is there in successive observations but it is small such that there is exponential decay. These two statements are not agreeing

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you misunderstood some text or an approximation was made. If the waiting timed between events are i.i.d. exponential r.v.s (i.e. with a non decaying fixed rate), the number of events follows a Poisson distribution. E.g. if a lot of radioactive material is decaying, strictly speaking the rate goes down over time, but when you observe it for a short time, the rate is almost constant.

Comment: Can you make it a little more clear. Does poisson distribution follows exponential decay or not

Comment: It has exponentially distributed inter-event waiting times. You would have to be more clear by what you mean by exponential decay for me to guess as to whether you mean the same thing.